# Is it possible to get list of all files REST API Chatter?

Tags: chatter, rest

Does anybody know if it's possible to get list of **all** files in REST API Chatter? There are examples but they are limited to owner only

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_users_files_general.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No this is not possible.You can't get all files in single request. You need to make separate request for each owner.

```
POST /services/data/v42.0/connect/files/users/me
```

the best you can do is make a request to get all users in the org and then make the chatter API request in a for loop. But if you are making this request from Salesforce then be careful about callout limit.